# Correct ConnectionFactory to use for sending remote JMS messages jboss 7.1.1

Tags: jms, jboss7.x, messaging, ejb-3.1, hornetq

What is the connection factory to use for sending messages outside the VM?

I see in *JBOSS/standalone/configuration/configuration_full.xml* two factories: **InVmConnectionFactory** and **RemoteConnectionFactory**. 
Are this the only available factories?

My actual configuration is:

SERVER *standalone_full.xml*

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:1.1">
    <hornetq-server>
        ...
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:1.1">
            <jms-connection-factories>
                <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory">
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
                    </entries>
                </connection-factory>
                <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory">
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="netty"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
                        <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
                    </entries>
                </connection-factory>
                <pooled-connection-factory name="hornetq-ra">
                    <transaction mode="xa"/>
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="java:/JmsXA"/>
                    </entries>
                </pooled-connection-factory>
            </jms-connection-factories>
        </subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:1.1">

    </hornetq-server>
</subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:1.1">
```

REMOTE MASCINE *standalone_full.xml*

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:1.1">
    <hornetq-server>
        ...
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:1.1">
            <jms-connection-factories> same factories as SERVER </jms-connection-factories>

            <jms-destinations>
                <jms-queue name="remoteQueue">
                    <entry name="jms/remoteQueue"/>
                    <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/remoteQueue"/>
                </jms-queue>
            </jms-destinations>
        </subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:1.1">
    </hornetq-server>
</subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:1.1">
```

Lookup from SERVER side, **server-application.ear**:

```
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
Destination destination = (Destination) ctx.lookup("jms/queue/remoteQueue");
```

Context build like:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
properties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://" + messageConnection.getHost() + ":" + messageConnection.getPort());
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, messageConnection.getUsername());
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, messageConnection.getPassword());
Context ctx = new InitialContext(properties);
```

Error I get:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.hornetq.api.core.client.loadbalance.RoundRobinConnectionLoadBalancingPolicy
Caused by: an exception which occurred:
    in field loadBalancingPolicy
    in field serverLocator
    in object org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQJMSConnectionFactory@36cdb608
```

If I try to deploy both applications **server-application.ear** and **remote-application.ear** in the same jboss(same VM), the messaging in working fine.

This problem occur when I use two jbosses (in the same macchine).

Anyone has any idea?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

InVmConnectionFactory references an in-vm-connector and can be used to send and receive messages when both the client and server are running in the same JVM. RemoteConnectionFactory references an netty connector and can be used to send and receive messages when client and server are running in different JVMs. You can define your own connection factory based on connector.

Regarding error, could you post complete stack trace ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Varsha. RemoteConnectionFactory AS-IS, using netty connector is not enough to connect to a remote macchine/jvm. The only way seems to be define your own connection factory, or change the actual "netty" configuration, configuring `connector` and `acceptor`with the IP/port where to send/listen.

Comment: The error still present when using two jboss in different macchines,when sending synch messages (waiting reply in a temp queue). Another curiosity is that the first time the message is correctly sent and reply correctly received. The second time I try to send I recevie the error. I will change the main question with details.

Answer (score 0):

This answer in the JBossDeveloper forum is the answer to the question:

[Remote JMS queue in JBoss AS 7.1](https://developer.jboss.org/message/721977)

Will not show a fully working example for Netty configuration making two nodes exchanging messages, but is very helpful to understand the concept.